# Skinning MSI pckages

Tags: .net, api, installation, windows-installer

I have a game application developed using C#. Is there any way to skin my MSI (installer) package ?

Comment: This will depend mostly on what tools are you using to create those MSI package.

Comment: Interesting that you only managed to find the product below after asking the question, when someone with your name appears to be its author.

Answer (score 5):

you can use 3rd party tools to skin your installer

check this : http://www.skincrafter.com/products/skincrafter-installer